# How to sort lines based on specific pattern in that line using python

Tags: python, sorting

I have such lines in file

```
1)  /^void UART0_ErrInterrupt(void)$/;" kind:function line:1367 signature:(void)
2)  /^tUI8 UART0_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:211 signature:( void )
3)  /^tUI8 UART1_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:281 signature:( void )
```

I need to sort these lines using python. I need this sorting done based on number after line: in each line. for example in above lines, the order of lines should be 2) , 3), 1) in ascending order. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sorted` with custom key

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     lines = sorted(f, key=lambda line: int(re.search(r"(?<=line:)\d+", line).group()))

>>> for l in lines:
...     print l

2)  /^tUI8 UART0_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:211 signature:( void )

3)  /^tUI8 UART1_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:281 signature:( void )

1)  /^void UART0_ErrInterrupt(void)$/;" kind:function line:1367 signature:(void)
```

Comment: You can totally remove the `.readlines()` call, simply pass `f` to `sorted()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that explains how sorting should be done:

```
def sortkey(line):
    # find the number after the first "line:" and convert it to an integer
    return int(re.search(r"(?<=line:)\d+", line).group())
```

and pass that function to the sorting function/method:

```
>>> sorted(lines, key=sortkey)
['2)  /^tUI8 UART0_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:211 signature:( void )', 
 '3)  /^tUI8 UART1_Get_TIE_Flag( void )$/;" kind:function line:281 signature:( void )', 
 '1)  /^void UART0_ErrInterrupt(void)$/;" kind:function line:1367 signature:(void)']
```

Comment: I tried using it, shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @AabhaGeed: You'll get the AttributeError if the regex can't find a match, so you have to define how to sort lines that don't match. I can't reproduce your second error message. Nothing in this code is trying to call an integer object, so maybe you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: I have added a filter for lines. I got rid of attibute error. The 'int' object is not callable still persists

Comment: @AabhaGeed: Well, where are you calling an integer object? What line triggers the error?

Comment: @AabhaGeed Have you accidentally made a variable named int? Check for `int = something`. Python doesn't stop you from overriding internal names. That could be causing problems with `return int()`

Comment: @Hiway: Ahh, that's a very good guess (although I would expect the other solution to then fail in the same way).